# Generic way of slicing on time in Pandas from beginning of Series to date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a bunch of tipping bucket raingauge data that I need to calibrate which have multiple calibration factors for different time periods. I've been going about this like:

```
data = pd.Series(range(100), pd.date_range('1950-01-01', freq='d', periods=100))

data.ix[:'2000-01-01'] *= CF1
data.ix['2000-01-02':'2000-05-12'] *= CF2
.
.
.
data.ix['2015-02-23':] *= CFn
```

For each station that I'm working with. I want to be able to apply these using a dictionary like so:

```
calibrations = {"Station1": [(slice(None), '2000-01-01', CF1),
                             ('2000-01-02', '2000-05-12', CF2),
                             ...]}

for station in calibrations:
    for start,end,cf in calibrations[station]:
        data.ix[start:end, station] *= cf
```

Which would be a lot more concise and easy to maintain by keeping the calibration information in a dict or csv file that can be imported.

How can I slice a Series with a DatetimeIndex in a generic way that accounts for the beginning and end time periods instead of having to do `data.ix[:timestamp]` and `data.ix[timestamp:]` for the beginning and ends of the data?

I've tried `data.ix[slice(None):timestamp]` for the beginning of the record but a pandas Timestamp or convertable string is required.

Hopefully this makes sense any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found the `truncate` method which will definitely work for this... Any other approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into the lambda function... or create a column from the index (taken from another post):

```
Series(s.reset_index().apply(f, axis=1).values, index=s.index)
```

Or the 'where' function.
I need to investigate this further for you (an interesting problem).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a lamda method for Series or DataFrame or lambda function at the top level of Pandas. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for this. I found out that to do what I've mentioned I needed to replace   `slice(None)` with simply `None`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I resolved my issue by replacing `slice(None)` with `None`
which allows me to use the same `.ix[start:end]` syntax to represent the beginning or end of the series by using `None` instead of a string denoting the first our last timestamp.